# Как записать в один файл json некоторые данные с отступом, а некоторые без

Tags: python, json

Как сделать так, чтобы в один файл json некоторые данные записались с отступом, а некоторые без.

Код:

```
import json

def readInt(file, size):
    return int.from_bytes(file.read(size), "little")

with open("bin.dat", 'rb') as datFile:
    datFile.read(8)
    size = readInt(datFile, 4)
    clubs = []
    for i in range(500):
        print(f"#{i + 1}/{size} - {hex(datFile.tell())}")
        club = {}
        club['info1'] = readInt(datFile, 1)
        club['info2'] = readInt(datFile, 2)
        club['info3'] = [(readInt(datFile, 4)) for i in range(5)]
        club['info4'] = [(readInt(datFile, 4)) for i in range(readInt(datFile, 2))]
        clubs.append(club)

with open("done.json", 'wt') as jsonFile:
    json.dump(clubs, jsonFile, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)
```

Результат получается таким:

```
[
  {
    "info1": 0,
    "info2": 5850,
    "info3": [
      6528,
      64798,
      9939,
      4294967295,
      4294967295
    ],
    "info4": [
      28331,
      28160,
      29580,
      29602,
      29676,
      26765,
      27123,
      27771,
      45129,
      27444,
      29478,
      66206,
      28056,
      27416,
      29048,
      27388,
      и так далее (длинный список)
```

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы номера в "info4" шли без отступа? То есть:

```
"info4": [28331, 28160, 29580, 29602...]
```

А всё остальное осталось неизменным.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16264515/json-dumps-custom-formatting

Comment: @Yaant сложно... Если ли что-то попроще?

Comment: @Yaant подскажите как это использовать?